# Bitcoin JSON-RPC API method createrawtransaction returns 'Invalid amount'

Tags: httprequest, bitcoin, json-rpc

I'm trying to create transaction using bitcoin core api. I use this request:

```
{
  "method":"createrawtransaction",
  "params":
 [
  [
   {"txid":"8d3c81d39d9d852b347490934b78f22137454706ea96c5cb61c1d1336d3c0440","vout":0},   
{"txid":"abd5a3c9abf946d90730b37f2f0dd2eab48cf1520bdccf2174a57c49991b5f81","vout":0}
  ],
  {
   "2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS":"0.00091644703125",
   "mqfU2qaG2BtrEqnovAbcRExvzHByvm1rPB":"0.0151"
  }
 ]
}
```

But it returns error: Invalid amount.
Maybe float value for first output is too long, but I never found limitations for its length.
Is there some limitations of this kind? Or is there another error?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the quotes around your amount value.

From

```
{
   "2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS":"0.00091644703125",
   "mqfU2qaG2BtrEqnovAbcRExvzHByvm1rPB":"0.0151"
}
```

To

```
  {
   "2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS": 0.00091644703125,
   "mqfU2qaG2BtrEqnovAbcRExvzHByvm1rPB": 0.0151
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fix the number of digits after the decimal by rounding and remove the quotes. I'm not sure how many digits you'd need for bitcoin but in my case it was 8. So maybe something like

```json
{
  "method":"createrawtransaction",
  "params":
 [
  [
   {"txid":"8d3c81d39d9d852b347490934b78f22137454706ea96c5cb61c1d1336d3c0440","vout":0},   
{"txid":"abd5a3c9abf946d90730b37f2f0dd2eab48cf1520bdccf2174a57c49991b5f81","vout":0}
  ],
  {
   "2N2DgdTtbrfBg65c1DrnuzJnAvSWWr4gkNS": 0.00091645,
   "mqfU2qaG2BtrEqnovAbcRExvzHByvm1rPB": 0.0151
  }
 ]
}
```